# publishing progress in shared class in doBackgorund in AsyncTask

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-asynctask

I have several different `AsyncTasks` that need to perform the same shared basic operation and show progress while doing so. Rather than copying a lot of code several times (with progress showing in each) is there a way to share the code by passing in the other class? The `AsyncTasks` are very different and you can't just pass in the Abstract, which has a protected `publishProgress()` method anyway. Looked at a bunch of examples and tried to a lot of different variations without success.

So here are the details...lets say we have two different tasks doing different stuff, but sharing the need to hit a server, download a number of files and then put them in a DB (and then do other stuff):

```
public class ExampleTaskFragment extends ListFragment {

    private ProgressDialog mProgress;

    private void hideProgress() {
        mProgress.dismiss();
    }

    private void showProgress(String message) {
        mProgress = ProgressDialog.show(getActivity(), null, message, true, false);
    }

    protected void updateProgressMessage(String message) {
        mProgress.setMessage(message);
    }

    public class TaskA extends AsyncTask<Object, String, ArrayList<A>> {

        public void progressUpdate(String... values) {
             publishProgress(values);
        }

        @Override
         protected void onCancelled() {
              hideProgress();
         }
         @Override
         protected void onPreExecute() {
             showProgress("Stuff before shared...");
         }
         @Override
         protected ArrayList<A> doInBackground(Object... params) {

            // DoStuffPublish is the common stuff both tasks share
            DoStuffPublish dostuff = new DoStuffPublish(this);
            return doMoreStuffA();
         }

         @Override
         protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<A> result) {
             updateProgressMessage("After shared stuff...");
             hideProgress();
         }  

         ArrayList<A> doMoreStuffA() {
            return new ArrayList<A>();
         }
    }

    public class TaskB extends AsyncTask<Object, String, ArrayList<B>> {

        public void progressUpdate(String... values) {
             publishProgress(values);
        }

        @Override
         protected void onCancelled() {
              hideProgress();
         }
         @Override
         protected void onPreExecute() {
             showProgress("Stuff before shared...");
         }
         @Override
         protected ArrayList<B> doInBackground(Object... params) {

            // DoStuffPublish is the common stuff both tasks share
            DoStuffPublish dostuff = new DoStuffPublish(this);
            return doMoreStuffB();
         }

         @Override
         protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<B> result) {
             updateProgressMessage("After shared stuff...");
             hideProgress();
         }  

         ArrayList<B> doMoreStuffB() {
            return new ArrayList<B>();
         }
    }
}

public class DoStuffPublish {

    private AsyncTask task;

    public DoStuffPublish(AsyncTask task) {
        super();
        this.task = task;
        doSharedStuff();
    }

    protected void publishProgress(String message) {
        if (task instanceof TaskA) {
            ((TaskA)task).progressUpdate(message);
        }
        else if (task instanceof TaskB) {
            ((TaskB)task).progressUpdate(message);
        }
    }

    public  void doSharedStuff() {

        publishProgress("Doing Shared stuff...");

        // Do lots of shared things here...

        publishProgress("Done doing shared stuff...");

     }
}
```

This code has been cobbled together - so don't get too hung up on the syntax. The concept it there...I want to have a shared class I can call in 2 or more tasks that can share that code and still publish updates. I have tried putting the ProgressDialog in the tasks and outside without success. When I have done so I get "Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch it's views". And in the debugger you can see the two different threads - the original main UI thread and the thread created in the  Form doInBackground(Object... params).

I fear this may not be possible...

Comment: You sound like you need to implement a task manager.

Comment: It sounds like you were trying to call updateProgressMessage() in doInBackground(), which won't work because it is not running in the UI thread. I think you need to override AsyncTask.onProgressUpdate() and call updateProgressMessage() inside of it in order to update the dialog in response to your calls to publishProgress()

Comment: Anyone have an example of this actually working? I tried a boatload of different ways of doing this.

Comment: robinj - I tried overriding the onProgressUpdate without success - perhaps I was implementing it incorrectly though. If you have an example of that I would much appreciate it!

Comment: That code doesn't actually do anything with the `DoStuffPublish` instances, is that just an artifact of translating from your original code?  I recommend you take this simplified code and make it into an actual working app that mirrors your real code as closely as possible.  If that still doesn't work, post the updated code and then we can see what code you're actually running.  Right now I'm just guessing at what problems are due to the code being "just cobbled together" and what are real problems.  If that does work, figure out what's different from your real app.

Answer (score 0):

robinj - had it correct, just needed to read his/her answer a little better. The trick was to code it like this:`public class ExampleTaskFragment extends ListFragment {

```
private ProgressDialog mProgress;

private void hideProgress() {
    mProgress.dismiss();
}

private void showProgress(String message) {
    mProgress = ProgressDialog.show(getActivity(), null, message, true, false);
}

protected void updateProgressMessage(String message) {
    mProgress.setMessage(message);
}

public class TaskA extends AsyncTask<Object, String, ArrayList<A>> {

    public void progressUpdate(String... values) {
         publishProgress(values);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values) {
        updateProgressMessage(values[0]);
    }
    @Override
     protected void onCancelled() {
          hideProgress();
     }
     @Override
     protected void onPreExecute() {
         showProgress("Stuff before shared...");
     }
     @Override
     protected ArrayList<A> doInBackground(Object... params) {

        // DoStuffPublish is the common stuff both tasks share
        DoStuffPublish dostuff = new DoStuffPublish(this);
        return doMoreStuffA();
     }

     @Override
     protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<A> result) {
         updateProgressMessage("After shared stuff...");
         hideProgress();
     }  

     ArrayList<A> doMoreStuffA() {
        return new ArrayList<A>();
     }
}

public class TaskB extends AsyncTask<Object, String, ArrayList<B>> {

    public void progressUpdate(String... values) {
         publishProgress(values);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values) {
        updateProgressMessage(values[0]);
    }

    @Override
     protected void onCancelled() {
          hideProgress();
     }
     @Override
     protected void onPreExecute() {
         showProgress("Stuff before shared...");
     }
     @Override
     protected ArrayList<B> doInBackground(Object... params) {

        // DoStuffPublish is the common stuff both tasks share
        DoStuffPublish dostuff = new DoStuffPublish(this);
        return doMoreStuffB();
     }

     @Override
     protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<B> result) {
         updateProgressMessage("After shared stuff...");
         hideProgress();
     }  

     ArrayList<B> doMoreStuffB() {
        return new ArrayList<B>();
     }
}
```

}

public class DoStuffPublish {

```
private AsyncTask task;

public DoStuffPublish(AsyncTask task) {
    super();
    this.task = task;
    doSharedStuff();
}

protected void publishProgress(String message) {
    if (task instanceof TaskA) {
        ((TaskA)task).progressUpdate(message);
    }
    else if (task instanceof TaskB) {
        ((TaskB)task).progressUpdate(message);
    }
}

public  void doSharedStuff() {

    publishProgress("Doing Shared stuff...");

    // Do lots of shared things here...

    publishProgress("Done doing shared stuff...");

 }
```

}
`

Note the

```
    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values) {
        updateProgressMessage(values[0]);
    }
```

Previously I had been trying to directly set the mProgress value, but it was in the wrong thread? Anyway thanks to robinj for the help! If you put an answer in I will thumbs it up...